# C# Marshalling unsigned char* array from C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, char, dllimport, unsigned

I am trying to marshal data from a C++ dll to C# that has an unsigned char* parameter.
I know this question has been asked before but I have tried most of the answers and still not getting far....the best I go was an array of bytes but that contained all 0000's

So here's the C++ function

```
int Hid_Read(int iIndex, unsigned char* pucaBuffer, int iSize);
```

Here's the C# DLLImport

```
[DllImport(@"The.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern int hid_Read(int iIndex, [Out] byte[] pucaBuffer, int iSize);
```

And the c# call:-

```
byte[] HID_ReceiveBuffer = new byte[128];
    
int intResult = hid_Read(HIDdeviceIndex, HID_ReceiveBuffer, 128);
    
for (int inteach = 0; inteach < 128; inteach++)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Data = " + HID_ReceiveBuffer[inteach].ToString());
}
```

This exits successfully but returns an array of 000's in the hid HID_ReceiveBuffer

Any help would be gratefully appreciated

Comment: If the buffer must be allocated by the caller, then simply `[Out]` is definitely wrong here.  Have you tried `[In, Out]`?

Comment: Neither of the comments above should be followed. No need for manual allocation. A byte array is fine. And the [Out] attribute has no effect because the array is pinned by the framework.

Comment: The interop looks fine to me. I suspect your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Alex F many thanks for your suggestion....tried it but with the same result.

Comment: @Gyorgy Koszeg and again, thanks for you suggestion...tried adding In but that also didn't work

Comment: @David Heffernam....yes I think you may be right as it's always the same result....I will look a bit deeper and report back if I find something else

Comment: @David Heffernan   Your a star!......Seems there  was nothing on the buffer for me to collect as I was doing things in the wrong order......I was communicating with an instrument via HID. Sent a command to take a reading. Then a command to generate the results. finally a command to collect the results.....the step I missed was to check the status of the instrument after sending the command to generate the results to make sure there was data to collect from the buffer. many thanks all for your advice